# How to add react native dependency in module?

Tags: android, react-native, module

When I add the react-native dependency in my app module, it's working, but when I am trying to add it on different module I am getting

> Error:(49, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.facebook.react:react-native:0.49.3

**Root Gradle:**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$projectDir/../android/node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

I think about moving node_modules to my module folder, but is a there better solution?

Comment: node_modules is under android folder?

Comment: @bennygenel but can it be a problem?

Comment: I think its a problem

Comment: So what would be the solution?

Comment: I don't think I understood the problem completely

Comment: In my "app" module I added compile project(':platform'),so it's okay when I add dependency in "app module",but it's not recognized when I add it on "platform" module.Simply "app" module should should see al the modules,but it should be invisible for another modules,I don't know if I explained my probelm well))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this,moving node_modules to my `platform` module and changing gradle files like this.

**Root Build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$projectDir/../../../platform/android/node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

**Platform Build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "$projectDir/android/node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
}
```